# How to access local Nuget Repo on Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, nuget, nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-code

So our company has a local Nuget repo that we use for our solution. In our `NuGet.config` file, we add the package sources as such

```
<packageSources>
   <add key="xxxxxx" value="\\tfs.xxxxxx.com\xxxxxxNuget" />
   <add key="Nuget Cache" value="\\tfs.xxxxxx.com\NugetCache" />
</packageSources>
```

When we restore packages on a PC with Visual Studio, this works fine (I can type the address into the windows Explorer, and it finds it).

Now, with ASP.NET 5 (aka ASP.NET Core - [Hanselman - ASP.Net 5 Is Dead](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)) and using Visual Studio Code on the Mac, when I run the command to restore packages, I get an error stating that the local package source doesn't exist.

My guess is that this is due to how file systems navigate network drives. But I can't figure out how to get this config to work such that I can restore the packages...

**Any ideas on how to access the local (local meaning on the network) repository?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer, you can't right now with what NuGet supports. Work around is to use the `/Volumes` drive after mounting the location with `smb`.
Only trouble is that you're going to need to make sure the drive is mounted when you try and restore packages, it won't happen automatically.